# zsh colored files directories

Tags: ubuntu, shell, zsh

I have a host for my VM, when it had a fresh install of Ubuntu the bash shell had colored directories and files.

How do I duplicate this with ZSH, i've customized my PS1 but I want to customize the color of directories as well... how do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It isn't your shell that determines whether output of `ls` is colorized.  You must run `ls --color=auto` (either as an alias, or explicitly) in order to get colorised `ls` output.  I suspect that your bash configuration included that alisa by default, but zsh doesn't for some reason.  Seems odd that Ubuntu would have crippled their zsh installation in such a fashion, but I've given up trying to work out what they're up to.

Comment: You can put the alias in your `~/.zshrc` file: `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`

Comment: I assume your answer is correct for Ubuntu, but since I landed on this question via a Google search and I'm using OSX: the exact flag may vary. For me, it was `ls -G`. Try `man ls` then search with `/color` to find what it is for any given OS.